# How to dynamically change directories with options in a bash function

Tags: bash

In my .bash_profile in my Mac, I have a short function to start my python virtual environment (working fine) and then change directory.

In my project files, I have used file names with endings in .git, .com or with no ending.  But for my virtual environments, I never used the endings.

Here is the function that I've created to fire up my virtual enviornment and chance to the relevant directory.

```
function wp(){
    source ~/.virtualenvs/$1/bin/activate
    PROJECTDIR="~/hacking/projects/$1"
    cd "$PROJECTDIR/" || cd "${PROJECTDIR}.git/" || cd "${PROJECTDIR}.com/"
}
```

As an example, one project I have has a directory name "yatma.git".

```
[~]$ wp yatma
-bash: cd: ~/hacking/projects/yatma/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: ~/hacking/projects/yatma.git/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: ~/hacking/projects/yatma.com/: No such file or directory
(yatma) [~]$ cd ~/hacking/projects/yatma.git/
(yatma) [yatma.git]$
```

Why do I get the 'no such file or directory' on the second line when it is the directory I want it to change into?  Am I approaching the problem wrong?  Should I rather split the string first and use two variables?

Comment: Tilde expansion isn't performed inside quotes. See the other question.

Comment: Okay, @gniourf_gniourf, thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: And by the way, you can get some inspiration with the auto complete function. It's mostly the same problem you're having! The only difference is that you have some extensions to deal with; either you keep them verbatim, or you use some globs and arrays. Good luck!